# How to custumize code suggestion for argument validation functions

Tags: matlab, arguments

I am trying to use argument validation to require that an input is a member of a predefined list of strings, which can be done using the `mustBeMember` function (see below). As expected, this throws an error if the user does not enter a valid argument, and additionally, **code suggestion** shows the user a list of the possible options when the user is typing out the function.

```
function out = myFunc1(arg)
    arguments
        arg {mustBeMember(arg, ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"])};
    end
    out = arg;
end
```

The problem is that I have many different functions that all use the same list of strings, so I have to copy and paste the list, which is unmaintainable. So I created a custom, reusable validation function that contains the list internally (see below).

```
function out = myFunc1(arg)
    arguments
        arg {mustBeValidOption};
    end
    out = arg;
end

function mustBeValidOption(arg)
    try
        mustBeMember(arg, ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"]);
    catch ME
        throwAsCaller(ME);
    end
end
```

Now I can use the `mustBeValidOption` validator in multiple functions. However, code suggestion no longer is functional.

So **this is my question**: How can I customize **code suggestion** for argument validation functions? Alternatively, is there a way to have the member list that is passed into the "mustBeMember" validator come from a separate file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet here is to use an `enumeration` as the [argument type](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-argument-validation-1.html#mw_ff920cc5-4815-463f-ac4c-f378aef24650). (You could use ["functionSignatures.json"](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/customize-code-suggestions-and-completions.html)... but I think that would end up being more duplication). For example:

```matlab
% ValEnum.m - enumeration of allowed options
classdef ValEnum
    enumeration
        opt1
        opt2
        opt3
    end
end
```

```matlab
function out = fcn1(arg, thing)
    arguments
        arg (1,1) double
        thing (1,1) ValEnum
    end
    out = string(arg) + ":fcn1:" + string(thing);
end
```

Here's what happened after I typed "fcn1(3, <kbd>Tab</kbd>":

[image: Shows tab completion of fcn]

Comment: Ah, thank you!! This does exactly what I want! And I can even have values associated with each option by saying "opt1 (1); opt2 (2); ..." in the enumeration definition. I had tried using "functionSignatures.json" but as you said I had to duplicate a lot and it is not easy for someone else to come in and add new options later. Thanks!